# Google Search by Image in Python

Tags: python, json, api, google-api, google-custom-search

Is there a way to use the Google search by Image feature in Python? I was considering taking an image file from a specified location and using that file to get relevant search results.
I have looked through the Google Custom Search API and cannot seem to find anything on this topic. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your browser accesses it using HTTP GET/POST. If you use the requests module in Python, you should be able to emulate how your browser does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet shows how to make a request to the Google Image Search API using Python. This sample assumes Python 2.4 or higher. You may need to download and install simplejson.

```
import urllib2
import simplejson

url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?' +
       'v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&userip=INSERT-USER-IP')

request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': /* Enter the URL of your site here */})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# Process the JSON string.
results = simplejson.load(response)
# now have some fun with the results...
```

Comment: use this link for more information https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

Comment: FYI "The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We encourage you to use the Custom Search API, which now supports image search." so don't use it for anything important as it probably won't be around much longer.